# BBC Consumer SQS Issues

Tags: amazon-sqs, consumer

I'm using the sqs-consumer node module package.

I have the following code:

```
 init: function () {
        var app = Consumer.create({
            queueUrl: Settings.getSetting("sendgrid-aws-sqs-queue"),
            batchSize: 1,
            visibilityTimeout: 30,
            waitTimeSeconds: 20,
            sqs: MarvelAWS.sqs,
            handleMessage: function (message, done) {
                try {
                    var msgBody;

                    try {
                        msgBody = JSON.parse(message.Body);
                    } catch (err) {
                        msgBody = null;
                        this._warn("parsing error handling SQS queue " + err, msgBody);
                    }

                    var environment = Settings.getSetting('environment');

                    if (validateMsg(msgBody) && (environment !== "prod" || this.LIST_TO_ID[msgBody.listId.toString()])) {

                        var userProfile = msgBody.profile,
                            timeSent = msgBody.timeSent,
                            action = msgBody.action,
                            listId = msgBody.listId.toString(),
                            suppressionListId = msgBody.suppressionListId.toString();

                        _.each(this.actionsMap[action], function (oneAction) {
                            this._debug(oneAction + ':' + listId + ' ' + msgBody.profile.email);

                            sendgridQueueManager.createQueue({
                                action: oneAction
                            });
                            sendgridQueueManager.push({
                                action: oneAction,
                                listId: listId,
                                suppressionListId: suppressionListId,
                                timeSent: timeSent,
                                profile: userProfile
                            });

                        }.bind(this));

                        EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_PULL_SUCCESS);
                    } else {
                        this._warn("validation error", msgBody);
                        EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_PULL_ERROR);
                    }
                    done();
                } catch (err) {
                    this._warn("error_processing_message " + err);
                    done(new Error('error processing message'));
                }

            }.bind(this)
        });

        app.on("message_received", function () {
            this._debug("message_received");
            EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
        }.bind(this));

        app.on("message_processed", function () {
            this._debug("message_processed");
            EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_MESSAGE_PROCESSED);
        }.bind(this));

        app.on("error", function (err, message) {
            this._warn("message_error " + err + " " + message);
            EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_PULL_ERROR);
        }.bind(this));

        app.on("processing_error", function (err, message) {
            this._warn("processing_error " + err);
            EngineMonitor.countOperation(EngineMonitor.OPS.SENDGRID_SQS_QUEUE_PULL_ERROR);
        }.bind(this));

        app.start();

        this._debug('sqs_app_start');
    },
```

sometimes a message gets added to the SQS queue but doesn't not get received by the consumer/
Here are my sqs queue settings:

[image]
Can someone please help?

In what cases do a message get added to the Queue and not received by the consumer?

Comment: "doesn't get received" -- ever? Or within the time you expect? Are the messages left in the queue, or are they somehow read and discarded without going through your consumer? Is it possible you have multiple instances of your consumer pointing to the same queue, and you're only looking at output from one of them?

Comment: Also, is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653227/bbc-consumer-sqs-polling?