# BBC consumer SQS polling

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I need to poll and SQS queue using node js. I tried using bbc consumer npm library but some messages don’t get received by the consumer. Does anyone have a better solution to polling an SQS using node?

Comment: "some messages don't get received by the consumer" - where are they going? They' don't get lost unless you're deleting them. Can you post the code you're using to demonstrate the problem, and clarify how you checked whether messages are being received?

Comment: Also, is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650834/bbc-consumer-sqs-issues?

Answer (score 0):

Use sqs-consumer it works great!